# Central Limit Theorem to evaluate $\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^n e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx$

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Use the central limit theorem to evaluate $$ \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^n e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx$$

From what I understand, the CLT says that the sequence of partial sums of i.i.d random variables $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n$ converges in distribution (once it's standardized by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation) to the CDF of a $N(0,1)$.

If we consider $P(S_n \le x)$ where $S_n$ is the sum of i.i.d exp(1) RVS, then by the CLT $P(\frac{S_n - n}{\sqrt{n}} 
\le x) \Rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{e^{-u^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}du$. Or equivalently, $P(S_n \le x) \approx N(\frac{x-n}{\sqrt{n}})$.

However, this isn't even remotely close to what I am suppose to find. I'm confused because I'm not quite sure how to to approach this problem.

Comment: Do you need an exact formula for this integral, or e.g. its $n\to\infty$ limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that it might be instructive to present a simple approach that does not rely on the Central Limit Theorem and Probability theory, but rather uses real analysis only.  To that end, we proceed.

We can assert that

$$\frac1{n!}\int_0^{n+1}e^{-x} x^n\,dx=\frac1{n!}\int_0^n e^{-x}x^n\,dx+\underbrace{\frac1{n!}\int_n^{n+1}e^{-x}x^n\,dx}_{=O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)}\tag1$$

Next, enforce the substitution $x\mapsto n-\sqrt n x$ to find that

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{n!}\int_0^{n+1}e^{-x} x^n\,dx&=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n!}\int_0^{\sqrt n} e^{-(n-\sqrt n x)}\left(n-\sqrt n x\right)^n\,dx+O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{n}(n/e)^n}{n!}\int_0^{\sqrt n}e^{\sqrt n x}\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt n}\right)^n\,dx+O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Next, we have the estimate

$$e^{\sqrt n x}\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt n}\right)^n=e^{\sqrt n x}e^{n\log\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt n}\right)}\le e^{-x^2/2}$$

Inasmuch as $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,dx<\infty$, the Dominated Convergence Theorem along with Stirling's Formula guarantee that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^{n+1}e^{-x}x^n\,dx&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}(n/e)^n}{n!}\int_0^{\sqrt n}e^{\sqrt n x}\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt n}\right)^n\,dx+O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}(n/e)^n}{n!}\int_0^{\infty}\xi_{[0,\sqrt n]}(x)e^{\sqrt n x}\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt n}\right)^n\,dx\\+O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty \lim_{n\to \infty }\left(\xi_{[0,\sqrt n]}(x)e^{\sqrt n x}\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt n}\right)^n\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Thank you Mark for your answer - I appreciate it. I think it's great.

Comment: @Doris_P You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @doris_p I've posted an answer [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810787/limit-of-e-n-sum-i-n4n-fracnii/3810893#3810893) that is related and generalizes the result herein.  Let me know your thoughts if you have a moment.

Answer (score 3):

We're actually using the large-$n$ approximation $S_n\approx N(n,\,n)$ to evaluate $P(S_n\le\color{blue}{n})$, so the probability is approximated as $\tfrac12$.